# don't know btnSearch.x and btnSearch.y value for post the Search Button

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

don't know btnSearch.x and btnSearch.y value for post the Search Button to click the search button with the following parameters?

```
payload={
    'today':'20180806'
    'sortBy':'',
    'alertMsg':'', 
    'ddlShareholdingDay':'04',
    'ddlShareholdingMonth':'06', 
    'ddlShareholdingYear':'2018', 
    'btnSearch.x':'????',
    'btnSearch.y':'???'
}

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = "url"
r=requests.post(html, data=payload)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

all_tables=[[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in 
soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr')]
stock_info=[[sub_item.replace('\r\n', '') for sub_item in item] for item in all_tables]
for stock in stock_info[2:]:
    print stock
```

Comment: You don't use `payload` in the request. Did you try to do this? What happens?

Comment: dears, yes, I don't know how to apply payload to make request

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests. But also take a look at the details of the POST request made by your browser when you click the search button. The request body contains some more data I don't understand.

Comment: Try `r=requests.post(html, data=payload)`

Comment: dears, but how can i click the button ?

Comment: Click the button?! You are sending HTTP request - you cannot "click" something... If you want to make a real click you can use Selenium, for instance

Comment: @Mary Did you try to execute the POST request without the `btnSearch.x` and `btnSearch.y` parameters? Does it work without them? If not, it will require some digging into the web site you want to use to understand how it behaves.

Comment: dears, no, it doesn't work, so that why trying to find the btnSearch values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `btnSearch.x` and `btnSearch.y` values are not important, they are just mouse coordinates of the `btnSearch` image (I think), and don't have any impact on the POST request.

However there are some important hidden fields (`__VIEWSTATE`, `__EVENTVALIDATION`) which are used by ASP.NET web applications. We can find those values and submit them with the POST data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'url'
s = requests.session()
r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

data = {i['name']: i.get('value') for i in soup.select('input')}
data['ddlShareholdingDay'] = '04'
data['ddlShareholdingMonth'] = '06'
data['ddlShareholdingYear'] = '2018'
data['btnSearch.x'] = '????'
data['btnSearch.y'] = '???'

r = s.post(url, data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
stock_info = [
    [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')] 
    for tr in soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr')
]
for stock in stock_info[2:]:
    print(stock)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with `curl` and was able to get the result using this simplified request:

```
$ curl 'url' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,application/pdf;q=0.1' \
-H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' --compressed \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data 'today=20180806&ddlShareholdingDay=04&ddlShareholdingMonth=08&ddlShareholdingYear=2018&btnSearch.x=0&btnSearch.y=0'
```

Please note that there is no cookie in this request. The two `btnSearch` parameters seem to be required but I was not able to observe any effect of different values. The request body contains only these fields:

```
today=20180806
ddlShareholdingDay=04
ddlShareholdingMonth=08
ddlShareholdingYear=2018
btnSearch.x=0
btnSearch.y=0
```

Using Python and requests such a request could look like this:

```
import requests

url = "url"
payload =  {
  "today": "20180806",
  "ddlShareholdingDay": "04",
  "ddlShareholdingMonth": "08",
  "ddlShareholdingYear": "2018",
  "btnSearch.x": "0",
  "btnSearch.y": "0"
}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

You can then proceed to parse `response.content` which is the HTML body.

Comment: dears, thanks, but when i changing "ddlShareholdingDay": "31",
  "ddlShareholdingMonth": "01",  "ddlShareholdingYear": "2018", actually nothing changed, that mean do not post any information of day, month and year, just using default.

Comment: Well, I think you will have to analyse the behaviour of this HTML form and the find out how the parameters work. I fear that we can be of little help with this. Maybe you can ask the people running this web site if there is an official documented API available. Maybe it even returns structured data like JSON so you don't have to scrape HTML.